# Switching from a mac x86 to arm m1 architecture, i ran into this error, anyone knows how fix it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bootsnap

when I try start rails with command:

- rails s,

   this is the response from the terminal:
- /.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.12.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in
- `require': **dlopen**(/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.13.6/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.bundle, 0x0009):
- tried: '/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.13.6/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.bundle' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e'))
- /Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.13.6/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.bundle (LoadError)

Comment: "How to solve problems" is not a real programming question.

Comment: I apologize for the inaccuracies. I corrected the question, now you understand the request? Thanks for your precious time! Very kind :-)

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow In the future if someone could show me a way to grow the network of knowledge of programmers using the rails framework or if they could recommend guides or courses or people to follow I would be grateful! Even with an economic fee!
Thank you all for your support and good luck to you all!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -2):

I understand that it is an incorrect way to solve the problem, but not being my field operating systems and processors, to solve the problem

- I bought a 200 € acer chromebook,
- I installed ubuntu xenial
- I have configured the work environment for rails

Now everything works at better.